# C# Nhibernate doing a copy after a load

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I'm trying to provide a method to update my database through nhibernate and returning a boolean.

```
public override bool Update(MyObject obj2)
        {
            if (session.IsOpen)
            {
                ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
                Domain.AudioSlogan obj1= session.Load<MyObject>(obj.PRIMARYKEY);
                if (obj1 == null)
                    return false;
                obj1 = obj2; // it's not working.
                transaction.Commit();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

**EDIT :** My database is not updated ( this is my problem ). The only way to make it work i found is to copy one by one  each properties : obj1.Name = obj2.Name; etc... Is it a reference problem ?

Comment: did you even read the compiler output??

Comment: What is not working? How is it not working? Where does obj.PRIMARYKEY come from? Are the types MyObject and Domain.AudioSlogan assignable to each other? Can you share the defintiions of those?

Comment: Are you trying to merge obj2 into obj1?

Comment: I try to copy my obj2 (data) into my obj1 to update my database. But i think it does a copy of the reference. The only way i found to update my database is to copy proprieties one by one. obj1.Name = obj2.Name etc...

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
obj1 = obj2 // it's not working.
```

To:

```
obj1 = obj2;
```

You forgot the:

```
;
```

Comment: It doesn't answer. It's just an error when i copied my code here.